# "du" inconsistent block size

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, du

I am getting inconsistent block sizes from `du` output

```
$ du -b acinclude.m4 aclocal.m4
2019    acinclude.m4
40203   aclocal.m4

$ du acinclude.m4 aclocal.m4
4       acinclude.m4  #  2019 /  512
40      aclocal.m4    # 40203 / 1024
```

What is causing this?

Comment: [`-b`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du) implies apparent size as well as 1-byte blocks. If you add `--apparent-size` to the second command, what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ du --apparent-size acinclude.m4 aclocal.m4
2       acinclude.m4
40      aclocal.m4
```